# How to multiply different table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables:

`table 1` has column `price`

`tabel 2` has column `total`

`table 3` has column `total_price`

**Question:**

I want the column `total_price` is the result from multiplication of 
`price` and  `total`:

`total_price = price * total`

im very newbie.

Comment: is there one to one relationship

Comment: its many_to_many beetwen table 1 and 2

Comment: how can you post model association

Comment: table_1

has_many : table_2,

table_2

has_many : table_1,

table_3

belongs_to :table_1
belongs_to :table_2

Comment: your association is confused me

Comment: can u fix it for me ?

Comment: @AsharMubasir can you post what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Table1.all.each_with_index do |el, index|
 Table3.create(total_price: el.price * Table2.all[index])
end
```

I am not going into all the details like relations, but the comments below make the point, but let's assume that these tables might have been just an extraction from Excel table or something like that.

Of course this is only if you want to create the third table. I am assuming that is what you want (?)

Comment: @Aleeks `Table2.all[index]` is this really worked or good idea to used? if some some of entries or row are not present or putted in different sequence. then this get crashed and give unwanted result because no mapping between both tables

Comment: @VishalJAIN , of course it is not a good idea :) the initial setup is wrong to start with. I have just the general idea how to do it as he is newbie, but there are plenty of things to update here as the question is quite open, but I have just concentrated how to give a general answer the question without getting much into the details

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to used it like this instead you should put other way some thing like  `@table2.select{|a| a.table1_id==el.id]}.first.total_price`. other wise op goes in wrong direction

Comment: No, to me it doesn't make sense to make assumptions where there are no place for it. I mean how do you know `a.table1_id==el.id` exists at all ? Suggesting it would be as wrong as suggesting `a.price * a.el.total`, which is by the way much cleaner and better. We don't know why those tables are formed like that, and why he is asking that. In any-case, I would be happy to see some other answer to help him out. This is just a ad-hock suggestion just to get him started. I taught that was obvious here, rather then creating all application for him.